# Should user object be stored in JSON Web Token?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, token, jwt

My question is rather simple ***should we or should we not store a user object in the JWT's payload***?

For example:

#### WIth user object embedded:

```
{
  iss: "https://YOUR_NAMESPACE",
  user: user, // user object from database
  aud: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  exp: 1372674336,
  iat: 1372638336
}
```

Or is it better to store only a unique id of a user, like so:

#### With just the user id embedded:

```
{
  iss: "https://YOUR_NAMESPACE",
  sub: user.id, //only user id
  aud: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  exp: 1372674336,
  iat: 1372638336
}
```

---

**JSON Web Token Draft Spec:** https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token

---

Answer (score 4):

You can store any kind of information about the user in your token, but I do not think it is useful to store all user informations.

As HTTP is stateless, each time a user connects on your website or web app, the token is sent to the server to authenticate the user. So this token should be as small as possible (that is the aim of the JSON Compact Serialization format of JWT).

You should store an unique information to identify the user such as its email address or its ID (`aud: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"`).

When needed, you can request informations about the user to the server using API calls or any other protocol.